Assign Updated Time when a specific column change in SQL
I have this table with values:



DWKey
Original Id
PartnerProgramStatusDWKey
UpdatedTime
LastUpdatedDate




2614
3584
2
2023-11-10
2023-11-10


3731
3584
2
2023-12-20
2023-11-10


4436
3584
2
2024-01-02
2023-11-10


4454
3584
1
2024-01-02
2024-01-02


4888
3584
1
2024-01-09
2024-01-02


5343
3584
1
2024-01-15
2024-01-02


22600
3584
2
2024-08-16
2023-11-10


22909
3584
2
2024-08-21
2023-11-10


23264
3584
2
2024-08-27
2023-11-10



I am currently using FIRST_VALUE column for the LastUpdatedDate to get the updated date when the  PartnerProgramStatusDWKey changed. However, as you can see, the date column has the old last updated date as the program changed from 1 back to 2. So what I would like to have is whenever there is a change in the Program Status no matter what value, the last updated date will be equal to the updated date. Here is the desired output:



DWKey
Original Id
PartnerProgramStatusDWKey
UpdatedTime
LastUpdatedDate




2614
3584
2
2023-11-10
2023-11-10


3731
3584
2
2023-12-20
2023-11-10


4436
3584
2
2024-01-02
2023-11-10


4454
3584
1
2024-01-02
2024-01-02


4888
3584
1
2024-01-09
2024-01-02


5343
3584
1
2024-01-15
2024-01-02


22600
3584
2
2024-08-16
2024-08-16


22909
3584
2
2024-08-21
2024-08-16


23264
3584
2
2024-08-27
2024-08-16




Can you post your attempt along with the DDL+DML to create the sample data - that makes it much easier for someone to try and assist you.

(1) Does the LastUpdatedDate column shown in your first data table above exist in your initial data source or is that just showing the result of your current attempt? (2) Do you need to query or update the entire table in one operation, or do you need logic to calculate and set the LastUpdatedDate while inserting new rows?

We could approach this as a gaps and islands problem, with the minimum UpdatedTime value per island being the desired value.
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Original Id]
                                 ORDER BY UpdatedTime, DWKey) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Original Id], PartnerProgramStatusDWKey
                                 ORDER BY UpdatedTime, DWKey) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT DWKey, [Original Id], PartnerProgramStatusDWKey, UpdatedTime,
       MIN(UpdatedTime) OVER (PARTITION BY [Original Id],
                                           PartnerProgramStatusDWKey,
                                           rn1 - rn2) AS LastUpdatedDate
FROM cte
ORDER BY [Original Id], UpdatedTime, DWKey;


The above gaps-and-islands logic depends on having a well-defined order, but the source data has duplicate UpdatedTime values. Adding DWKey as a second ORDER BY value may be the fix, if ascending values imply order.  Fiddle.

@dr Yeah, that fixes it.

That works for me, thank you :)

One option is to use Case expression with analytic functions in two steps - first ( inner query LAG() Over() ) defining dates when value of PartnerProgramStatusDWKey is changed and second ( outer query Max() Over() ) populating dates that should have new LastUpdatedDate.
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a : 
    tbl ( DWKey, Original_Id, PartnerProgramStatusDWKey, UpdatedTime, LastUpdatedDate ) AS
      ( Select 2614,  3584, 2, Cast('2023-11-10' as Date), Cast('2023-11-10' as Date) Union All 
        Select 3731,  3584, 2, Cast('2023-12-20' as Date), Cast('2023-11-10' as Date) Union All
        Select 4436,  3584, 2, Cast('2024-01-02' as Date), Cast('2023-11-10' as Date) Union All
        Select 4454,  3584, 1, Cast('2024-01-02' as Date), Cast('2024-01-02' as Date) Union All
        Select 4888,  3584, 1, Cast('2024-01-09' as Date), Cast('2024-01-02' as Date) Union All
        Select 5343,  3584, 1, Cast('2024-01-15' as Date), Cast('2024-01-02' as Date) Union All
        Select 22600, 3584, 2, Cast('2024-08-16' as Date), Cast('2023-11-10' as Date) Union All
        Select 22909, 3584, 2, Cast('2024-08-21' as Date), Cast('2023-11-10' as Date) Union All
        Select 23264, 3584, 2, Cast('2024-08-27' as Date), Cast('2023-11-10' as Date) 
      )

--      S Q L : 
SELECT   a.DWKey, a.Original_Id, a.PartnerProgramStatusDWKey, a.UpdatedTime, 
         Case When PartnerProgramStatusDWKey = 
                             Coalesce( LAG( PartnerProgramStatusDWKey) 
                                            Over(Partition By Original_id Order By UpdatedTime, DWKey), 
                                       PartnerProgramStatusDWKey 
                                     )
              Then Coalesce( Max( New_LastUpdatedDate) 
                                  Over(Partition By Original_id Order By UpdatedTime, DWKey
                                       Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row),  
                             New_LastUpdatedDate 
                           )
         Else New_LastUpdatedDate
         End as LastUpdatedDate
FROM   ( Select    t.*,
                   Case When PartnerProgramStatusDWKey != 
                             Coalesce( LAG( PartnerProgramStatusDWKey) 
                                            Over(Partition By Original_id Order By UpdatedTime, DWKey), 
                                       PartnerProgramStatusDWKey 
                                     )
                        Then UpdatedTime
                   Else LastUpdatedDate
                   End as New_LastUpdatedDate
         From      tbl t
       ) a
ORDER BY a.Original_Id, a.UpdatedTime, a.DWKey

/*    R e s u l t : 
DWKey   Original_Id  PartnerProgramStatusDWKey  UpdatedTime  LastUpdatedDate
------  -----------  -------------------------  -----------  ---------------
  2614         3584                          2  2023-11-10   2023-11-10
  3731         3584                          2  2023-12-20   2023-11-10
  4436         3584                          2  2024-01-02   2023-11-10
  4454         3584                          1  2024-01-02   2024-01-02
  4888         3584                          1  2024-01-09   2024-01-02
  5343         3584                          1  2024-01-15   2024-01-02
 22600         3584                          2  2024-08-16   2024-08-16
 22909         3584                          2  2024-08-21   2024-08-16
 23264         3584                          2  2024-08-27   2024-08-16      */

See the fiddle here.

The above could be simplified to eliminate the reference to the original unreliable LastUpdatedDate column. I do not think the OP's original data has this column.  See this fiddle.

@TN  Quote no. 1 from question (first line) "I have this table with values:" end quote followed by table with LastUpdatedDate as the last column.

@TN The column exists and has the value from first row havimg the same PartnerProgramStatusDWKey. The OP's logic says that initial value stays untill the change of PartnerProgramStatusDWKey value (2 then 1 then 2 again)... Second appearance of PartnerProgramStatusDWKey = 2 needs new value for the LastUpdatedDate that should be "assigned" (OP's expression from the title) from UpdatedTime...
